# .NET WinForms high DPI Scaling - how to force forms to display correctly after display settings change?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, highdpi

I have a WinForms application built in .NET Core 3.1 that works fine on high DPI displays. My problem is whenever a new display is added or removed in Windows the forms just get that fuzzy look again. Restarting the application resolves this but I would like to redraw the forms appropriately whenever this happens.

I think I already found the appropriate system event to subscribe to but I just cannot make the forms redraw / repaint themselves correctly.

Subscribing to Windows event DisplaySettingsChanged like so:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
(...)
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateDpiOnOpenForms);
```

And then adding the event handler method which I could not get to work:

```
public static void UpdateDpiOnOpenForms(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) 
    { 
        //What would the correct command be here?
    }
}
```

How can all open forms be forced to redraw / repaint using the new default high DPI settings just like they do after the application starts?

Comment: Note that the Form class already provides `RescaleConstantsForDpi()`, `OnGetDpiScaledSize()`, [OnDpiChanged()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,5099) and  `OnDpiChangedAfterParent`, `OnDpiChangedBeforeParent` from Control. Also, the `DpiChanged` and the other related events. -- How did you set the DpiAwareness of your application?

Comment: Everything is left as defined in the .NET WinForms project template. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 v 16.8.4.
Do I need to create a manifest file and declare high dpi compatibility explicitly even in .NET Core?

Comment: [Application.SetHighDpiMode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.sethighdpimode). -- Since you're still building your app, my suggestion (just a suggestion and just mine) is to use .Net 5+ instead (or .Net Framework 4.8), leave .Net Core 3.1 go. -- Autoscale to Dpi.

Comment: Actually this command is executed when the application starts before any form is loaded: Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);

Comment: That's because `app.config` is not considered in .Net Core. `app.manifest` is and overrides any `Application.SetHighDpiMode()`. Ideally, you should set `HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2`, which is limited to some newer versions of Windows 10. If you plan on supporting more System versions, this must specified in the `app.manifest`. It's quite complex to get them all right all the time (mostly because this matter is  unresolved at its core). See: [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process), [...]

Comment: [...] [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows). If it gets *confusing*, it's because it is (again, at its core). A lot of testing required.

Comment: Since, apparently, you haven't configured your app to support High Dpi Awareness, you need to start from the configuration, then proceed with the Designer, which needs to take into consideration the Dpi scaling that occurs at run-time. Design your app at 100% scaling (always), scale to Dpi, use containers (Panels, TableLayoutPanels, FlowLayoutPanels and other custom containers) to layout and anchor your Controls: don't let them *float around* (ever). Handle and set the Font explicitly, using a Font built for this (Segoe UI, Microsoft Yahei UI etc. -> the `UI` part gives it away). Test a lot.

Comment: See also, e.g., [Automatic scaling in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Note the `Important` info box there if you switch the Version selector to .Net 5.

Comment: Like I stated in the question: the application scales fine when launched in a static environment (so I assume it is declaring itself as DPI-aware to the system). The problem arises when I switch from my notebook's internal display to an external display or extend the desktop. That's when the application needs to be restarted to have the UI display clearly.
Is this issue resolved in WPF?

Comment: That's what `HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2` is for. PLUS an application **designed** to support Dpi scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Use Control.Invalidate() method.

"Invalidates the specified region of the control (adds it to the control's update region, which is the area that will be repainted at the next paint operation), and causes a paint message to be sent to the control. Optionally, invalidates the child controls assigned to the control."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=net-5.0

Comment: The Invalidate() method did not work. I even tried iterating through one of the open form's controls one-by-one and it still did not help.